# Calculating mass/force it will take to topple a swing

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, mass, rotational-kinematics

I make a swing. The support legs of the frame are at a 45° angles. The height is 8 ft tall how heavy and how much force would cause the frame to topple? What is the equation. Let me know if you need any more hypothetical information.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! What are your thoughts? Please note that you are expected to have thoroughly searched for an answer before asking your question. And it's important to detail where you're stuck and why, in order to attract good answers. You can consider checking the [advice on writing good questions](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

We assume the following parameters just for simplicity, otherwise we may change them.

Length of rope hanging from the top bar of the swing 6 feet.
Weight of the boy being pushed by his dad 80 lbs.
Weight of swing 160 lbs.
Center of gravity of boy and swing together at (80/(80+160))*6= 2 feet from the swing hook.

Because the father pushes the kid ever so gently in small increments each time we can assume the angle of swing is growing as a smooth function gradually up to the first time when

$2*cos(theta) > half- of -the- base- of-triangle- of swing frame$

And

$ half-of -the-base=8(height)/2=4$

Then

$cos(theta)> 4/2! wrong$

So we stablish with this configuration the swing will never topple.

It would topple if the center of gravity moves to 4 feet from the hook at a swing angle of 90 degrees. Which means the boy must be 320lbs, which is not a healthy weight!

Answer (score 0):

The diagram below shows the swing frame ABC with the rope or chain CD. The swinger sits at D. The tension $T$ in the chain or rope varies as the person swings, being maximum when CD is vertical downwards. The frame will start to topple about corner A when the moment (torque) of tension $T$ just exceeds the moment of the weight $W=Mg$ of the frame about A. The frame will not actually topple until AC becomes vertical, but the swinger will be uncomfortable if corner B lifts off the ground; this calculation avoids that happening.

[image]

The moment of weight is $aW$ where $2a$ is the length of side of the frame. This does not change as the person swings. $W$ does not include the weight of the person on the swing, the seat or the chain. The latter together have mass $m$ and contribute to tension $T$. When the swing reaches angle $\theta$ to the vertical then the moment of the tension about A is $2aT\sin(\theta-\alpha)$ where $2\alpha$ is the angle of the frame at C. Assuming the frame is an equilateral triangle then $\alpha=30^{\circ}$.

The tension $T$ varies as the person swings. If the maximum angle of swing is $\theta_0$ then the swinging motion is described by
$\theta=\theta_0\cos\omega t$
where $\omega \approx \sqrt{g/L}$ is the angular frequency of the swing, and $L$ is the length of CD. The angular frequency of the chain CD is
$\frac{d\theta}{dt}=\dot\theta=-\omega\theta_0\sin\omega t$
The tension in the chain is
$T=mg\cos\theta+mL\dot\theta^2=mg(\cos\theta+\theta_0^2-\theta^2)$
The moment of $T$ about A is
$2aT\sin(\theta-\alpha)=2mga(\cos\theta+\theta_0^2-\theta^2)\sin(\theta-\alpha)$

Assuming that the maximum angle of swing is $\theta_0=90^{\circ}=\pi/2$ radians, then the maximum value of $(\cos\theta+\theta_0^2-\theta^2)\sin(\theta-\alpha)$ is approx $0.94$ when $\theta \approx 1.066$ rad. Then the maximum moment of $T$ is approx $1.88mga$.

So corner B starts to lift off the ground when $1.88m \approx M$. **The weight of the frame should be at least 2 times the weight of the person on the swing plus the seat.**

The dimensions of the frame are not important, nor is the length of the swing CD. I have assumed that the frame is equilateral : a taller, narrower frame will increase the weight required for the frame.

Comment: Thanks Sammy! I’ve been wanting to build a swing but have had this nagging question for quite some time. When someone asks me to build a box I don’t just build it.  I have to know what the holding strength would be and then the question presents itself before you know it I never make the box lol. Have a good night